# Exit hidden console app

Tags: c#, console-application

I have this prank app and I need a way to terminate it with the keyboard because it moves the mouse and I can't access the task manager while it is running. I would like to terminate it with alt+p.

```
        drunkMouseThread.Start();
        drunkKeyThread.Start();
        drunkSoundThread.Start();
        drunkPopupThread.Start();

        //Where I need to kill it
        bool setTrue = true;

        while ( setTrue == true)
        {
            if (Keys.KeyCode == Keys.NumLock)
            {
                break;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(50);
        }

        //Kill all threads and exit the app
        drunkMouseThread.Abort();
        drunkKeyThread.Abort();
        drunkSoundThread.Abort();
        drunkPopupThread.Abort();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope below url might be useful to you
[source 1](https://gist.github.com/Stasonix/3181083) or
[Processing Global Mouse and Keyboard Hooks in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C)